# error when install node modules ---common.gypi not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

when I run npm install , the node modules included in the package.json should be installed, however, there are following errors:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/zeparser/0.0.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/options
gyp: C:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\.node-gyp\0.10.5\common.gypi not found (cwd: c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\csfv_misc_module\node_modules\email-templates\node_modules\juice\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify) while reading includes of binding.gyp while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (h:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:415:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:784:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
gyp ERR! command "node" "h:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\csfv_misc_module\node_modules\email-templates\node_modules\juice\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\contextify
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.5
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v0.9.5
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/tinycolor
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/options
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/commander
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat 'c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\csfv_misc_module\node_modules\email-templates\node_modules\juice\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\cssstyle\lib\properties\borderBottomWidth.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "h:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "h:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! cwd c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! path c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\csfv_misc_module\node_modules\email-templates\node_modules\juice\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\cssstyle\lib\properties\borderBottomWidth.js
npm ERR! fstream_path c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module\node_modules\csfv_misc_module\node_modules\email-templates\node_modules\juice\node_modules\jsdom\node_modules\cssstyle\lib\properties\borderBottomWidth.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack h:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fstream\lib\writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! contextify@0.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! `cmd "/c" "node-gyp rebuild"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the contextify@0.1.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the contextify package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls contextify
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 5.1.2600
npm ERR! command "h:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "h:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i"
npm ERR! cwd c:\Documents and Settings\Jicheng An\csfv_cms_module
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.5
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm WARN engine mong.socket.io@0.9.0: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x"} (current: {"node":"v0.10.5","npm":"1.2.18"})
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-openid
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-oauth
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/passport-oauth
```

I don't know what the common.gypi is and why the error happens.
can anyone help me to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you module require compilation, most of the modules in npm have precompiled binaries for Win Mac Linux, but this one require compilation with node-gyp. https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp

For Windows it will actually create .sln and .cxproj files for C source files of the module.
And it will do this using Python. After that it will run msbuild to build the solution.
You will need Visual Studio at least express in this case